# onClick вновь созданным элементам

Tags: jquery

Есть событие onClick, реагирующее на щелчок по элементу определенного класса:

```
jQuery('.a').on('click', function() {
    ...
});
```

Проблема в том, что когда добавляю элемент с классом `.a` динамически, то событие `onClick` на нем не срабатывает.

Comment: jQuery.on() - http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 3):

на динамически создаваемые элементы обработчики вешать надо через родительский элемент, например как-то так

```
$('document').on('click', 'your_elem', function(){ ... })
```

Comment: Нужно, чтобы одна и та же функция реагировала как на предустановленные, так и на динамические элементы. Значит, ее надо как-то назвать, и потом вместо `function(){...})` указывать ее имя? Или синтаксис другой будет?

Comment: @nup, если хотите - можете спокойно указывать обычные, не анонимные функции. К описанному вами, правда, оно никак не относится.

Comment: @kiberlain - `$(document).on(...` - без кавычек.